# How do I collect data points from a list plot within an ellipse graphic in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Updated:

I have a listplot of data and I would like to collect all the data points within a specific boundary of a circle graphic that overlaps the listplot in Mathematica.

Is something like this possible?

The ellipse I have made is of the form

```
{c, s, \[Theta]} = 
 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[f, {"Centroid", "SemiAxes", "Orientation"}]
Show[Rasterize[p], Graphics[{Red, Rotate[Circle[c, s], \[Theta]]}]]
```

Can you help me fit your bottom-most solution into a form where I can input my ellipse with the Centroid, SemiAxes, and Orientation properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}]
r = 1/5;
center = {1/6, 1/4};
sd = Select[data, EuclideanDistance[#, center] < r &]
Show[ListPlot@data, 
     Graphics@Circle[center, r], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@sd}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

For an ellipse

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}]
r = 1/5;
f1 = {1/6, 1/4};
f2 = {1/3, 1/5};
sd = Select[data, EuclideanDistance[#, f1] + EuclideanDistance[#, f2] < r &]
Show[ListPlot@data, 
     RegionPlot[EuclideanDistance[{x, y},f1] + EuclideanDistance[{x, y},f2] <r, 
                {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@sd}], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit 2**

Better code

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}]
r = 1/5;
f1 = {1/6, 1/4};
f2 = {1/3, 1/5};
inside[{x_, y_}, {f1_, f2_}] := Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, i], {i, {f1, f2}}];
sd = Select[data, inside[#, {f1, f2}] < r &];
Show[ListPlot@data,
     RegionPlot[inside[{x, y}, {f1, f2}] < r, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}],
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@sd}],
  AspectRatio -> 1]
```

**Edit 3**

Here you have the whole thing translated to your `ComponentMeasurements` output

```
(*{c,s,t}=1/.ComponentMeasurements[f,{"Centroid","SemiAxes",\
"Orientation"}] *)
c = {.3, .4}
s = {.4, .2}
t = Pi/8

{s1, s2} = s
center = {cx, cy} = c
f = Sqrt[s1 s1 - s2 s2]
f1 = {f1x, f1y} = {cx + f Cos[t], cy - f Sin[t]}
f2 = {f2x, f2y} = {cx - f Cos[t], cy + f Sin[t]}
r = 2 Sqrt[f f + s2 s2]

data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2}];

sd = Select[data, EuclideanDistance[#, f1] + EuclideanDistance[#, f2] < r &];
Show[
 ListPlot@data, 
 RegionPlot[ EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, f1] + EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, f2] < r,
              {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}], 
 Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point@sd}], 
AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much belisarius. My Circle is actually an ellipse, but I think I can manage to translate your answer! This is perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @tquarton Please don't contact me by mail for further details, as that can't help others. If you need more help, post a comment here or update your question (the second option is better). Tnx!

Comment: Alright, I updated my question. My fault for not being very specific in the beginning. Thank you for all the help belisarius.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly, but I ran into another problem. I posted a related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11812779/how-do-i-transform-a-rasterized-graphics-coordinates-back-to-its-original-listp) if you are interested in taking a look at it. I made it a separate question because its more related to image processing.